# For each passenger, get the information how many other passengers are in the same cart

Tags: count, frequency

I have a table;

```
INSERT INTO passengers(id, name, cart_id)
VALUES (1, Uolevi, 1), (2,Maija, 1), (3, Kaaleppi, 2), (4, Kotivalo, 4), (5, Juustina, 4), (6, Vihtori, 4)
```

Expected result:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Uolevi   |   1      |
| Maija    |   1      |
| Kaaleppi |   0      |
| Kotivalo |   2      |
| Juustina |   2      |
| Vihtori  |   2      |
```

I used COUNT(*) and GROUP BY cart_id. Then the column Name only shows the first name of each cart_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4b80e/6/0

```
select
  p1.id
  ,p1.name
  ,(select count(*) from Passengers p2 
      where p1.cart_id = p2.cart_id and p1.Id <> p2.Id ) as CountOfOthers
from
  Passengers p1
```

Basically the sub query gets the count of passengers with the same `[Passenger.Cart_Id]` excluding themselves.

Output

```
id  name        CountOfOthers
1   Uolevi      1
2   Maija       1
3   Kaaleppi    0
4   Kotivalo    2
5   Juustina    2
6   Vihtori     2
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not expect that it works that way. Another lesson learnt.

Comment: I wonder if the he subquery here is considered INNER JOIN (self join)?